# Backup Log is not letting Log file being reused

Tags: sql-server-2008, backup

I have a DataBase in a Sql Server 2008 which is performed a backup log every 2 hours with a job schedule.

but sometimes my file log gets full and it is not being reused, even after I perform another backup log using the following transaction (which the job use too):

```
BACKUP LOG  [MyDB] 
TO  DISK = N'b:\backup\myDB.bkp' 
WITH  INIT ,
NOUNLOAD ,
NAME = N'MyDB Backup',  
NOSKIP,
STATS = 10,
NOFORMAT
```

I look up in many questions, but no one says something that really worked for me so far.

Comment: is there any reason why my log file is not being reused?

Comment: Thanks God I found the problem .

It is always an open transaction (begin tran), while my log backup is performing. I changed both schedules and now everything is working fine.